# can't get token back when using ionic and react with oidc

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, openid-connect

I'm trying to build an app that uses oidc for authentication, and I wonna do it using Ionic and React,
I tried installing this package and using it: [react oidc context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-oidc-context),
and here the configs of mine:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const oidcConfig: AuthProviderProps = {
    authority: "my_auth_provider",
    client_id: "my_app_id",
    redirect_uri: "ai.makan:/oauthcallback",
    scope: "openid offline",
  };

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}>
          <IonRouterOutlet>
            <Route exact path="/home">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Redirect to="/home" />
            </Route>
          </IonRouterOutlet>
        </AuthProvider>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  );
};
```

and here is the button that launches the action:

```
const handleSignIn = (e?: any) => {
    setButtonColor("blue");
    const token = auth.signinRedirect();
    alert(`your token is: ${JSON.stringify(token)}`);
    setShowData(JSON.stringify(props));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.length > 0) {
      // alert(`your data is: ${JSON.stringify(userData)}`);
      alert(`your data is: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
    }
  }, [data, props]);

  useEffect(() => {
    alert(`auth active navigator: ${auth.isAuthenticated}`);
  }, [auth]);
```

when triggering the function it opens the browser and signs us in, yet I can't access any data, neither the token nor user credentials within my app, so the app doesn't recognise the user even thought he just authenticated him self